# About Schauder Basis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose M is a compact Lie Group, is there a Schauder basis for L^1(M)?

Comment: If you're talking about Haar measure and your group is connected, then I'm fairly sure L^1(M) coincides with $L^1([0,1]^d)$ where $d$ is the dimension, which makes me suspect the answer is yes. If you want a Schauder basis which is related somehow to the group structure on $M$ then I'm not sure what kinds of candidate bases there might be.

Comment: Downovted for lack of clarity and for assuming that we should "obviously" know that when you say "compact Lie group" you meant a $k$-torus, and that when you asked for a Schauder basis you wanted to know if the characters form a Schauder basis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every separable $L_1$ space is isomorphic to $\ell_1$ or $L_1(0,1)$ and thus has a Schauder basis. Look at, for example, Classical Banach spaces by Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri.  Other books probably have it, too; see Albiac-Kalton Topics in Banach space theory or Wojtaszczyk's Banach spaces for analysts.

Comment: Suppose Γ is a comapct Lie Group， G is its dual， then I want to ask what can we say about G?

Comment: What do you mean by the dual of a compact non Abelian group?

Comment: XXX if that is what you want to ask, then that is what you should have asked. Also "what can we say about X" is in my view not a very well-posed question, in this or any other academic discipline. 

Comment: @Yemon (or whomever), do you remember why the characters cannot be ordered to be a Schauder basis for $L^1(G)$ for any compact Abelian metrizable group $G$?  No credit for pointing to McGehee, Pigno, Smith, which anyway would cover just the case of the torus. I think Wojtaszczyk proved something more general (that a basis for $L_1$ that is bounded away from zero cannot be uniformly integrable, or something close to this), but ruling out the characters is easier, IIRC.

Comment: Of course Γ and G should be Abelian.

Comment: "Of course"????

Comment: @Yemon Choi. What else when you start a discussion about Lie groups? :)

Answer (score 10):

First, let me reinforce what Yemon wrote. I came close to downvoting your question and also voting to close.  Was it so hard to write

Title: Can the characters be ordered to form a Schauder basis for $L^1(G)$

Question: Let $G$ be a compact Abelian metrizable group.  Can the continuous characters on $G$ be ordered to be a Schauder basis?

You should have then written some motivation and what you already know.

Now for a complete answer.  Szarek (not Wojtaszzczyk) proved that any normalized (or semi normalized) basis for any $L_1$ space contains a subsequence equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$.  See

Szarek, S. J. Bases and biorthogonal systems in the spaces $C$ and $L_1$. Ark. Mat. 17 (1979), no. 2, 255–271.

This immediately implies that the characters cannot be ordered to be a Schauder basis.  In a paper referenced by Szarek, Olevskii proved that no Schauder basis for $L_1$ can be orthonormal and uniformly bounded; so the case of characters was known before Szarek's paper.  I do not know if anyone had checked that case before Olevskii;  probably not.